# access volumes set in docker-compose.yml from dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have my project architecture like this:

```
.
├── app/
├── context/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── .dockerignore
│   └── php.ini
├── database/
├── http/
├── composer.json
└── docker-compose.yml
```

and in `docker-compose.yml` I have the following configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
  app:
    container_name: "ERP"
    restart: always
    build: 
      context: ./context
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports: 
      - '8000:80'
    links: 
      - db_server
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
  db_server:
    container_name: "db_server"
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports: 
    - '3306:3306'
```

But when I set the `Dockerfile` content to set up the application with `docker-compose up`, having `Dockerfile` content as this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN cat composer.json
```

It says `"No such file or directory composer.json"`. Why?

### **UPDATE**

I managed to solve the problem based on ***ENTRYPOINT*** configuration ..

as far I understand - I'm new to docker - , the ENTRYPOINT defines an entry script running at the beginning of a container , thus , starting that script will be definitely in the run time of the container and after the initializations specified by docker-compost.yml file .. so the contents of the actual context will be available to the script to see it in the time it runs ..

Thank you all for your answers .

Comment: Try use `RUN ls -al` to see what files are in working directory?

Comment: it returnd context's directory files ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you define the context to be "./context", so you are stuck into this folder, where composer.json isn't.

Use "." for the context. and context/Dockerfile for the dockerfile.
Then mounting '.' will mount the whole directory, and not only the ./context one.

Comment: it makes sense .. , I moved the files inside context directory to the root , set the context to be .  , but it is stuck now with " building app ...' why is that ?

Comment: Just "building app" ? didn't the dockerfile get interpreted at all ?

Comment: Im afraid its a memory issue

Comment: you can try using the verbose option : docker-compose --verbose up

Answer (score 0):

The build process to create an image occurs before the runtime process that takes that image and runs a container. The compose file includes a build section to allow you to easily build the image before running it, but all of the other parts of the compose file define runtime configurations like volume mounts and networking.

At build time, you do not get to specify the volume sources, at most you can define a required volume target in the image with a VOLUME step. (Note if you do that, future RUN steps within the Dockerfile may have issues modifying that directory since many build tools mount an anonymous volume as you've requested, but only capture the changes to the container filesystem, not the volume filesystem).

If you need the contents of a file or directory in your image, you must perform a COPY or ADD step in the Dockerfile to copy from the build context (typically imported as `.` or the current directory) into the image.

Answer (score 0):

Key [build.context](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#context) define a path to a directory containing a `Dockerfile`. This is a context of building image, and during build process docker doesn't have access to `composer.json` file (it is out of the context).

Command [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) runs command during build. If you want to run it when container is starting, you should use [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
CMD cat composer.json
```